# Which gesture recognizer is being used?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, ios9

In our new app if a user swipes a certain way, something happens.  I think its a UISplitViewController in compact view looking at a detail going back to the master list - and getting the navigation controller incorrect.  How can I confirm what gesture recognizer is responding to the gesture?

Comment: Is it left swipe ? InteractivePopGesture recognizer ?

Answer (score 1):

The `handleGesture:` message includes a pointer to the gesture recognizer that is sending the message. Use that to compare it and see which one is being triggered.

(Actually it looks like there are 2 possible signatures: One with no parameter, and one that passes in the source gesture recognizer. Be sure to use the second form.)

Comment: I don't see that in the API... which object has that function?

Comment: Or do you mean what selector I'm using in my added gestures?  I think the gesture that we are researching is a built in gesture that we did not contribute

Comment: Take a look at the `initWithTarget:action:` method of UIGestureRecognizer. The action method either includes no parameters, or one, which is the gesture recognizer that triggers the action. Same with the `addTarget:action:` method

Comment: Thanks Duncan but I think we are curious about gesture recognizers from the frameworks.

Comment: Your question is clear as mud. You need to go back and edit your question to explain what you are trying to do.